# How to configure an agent so that it can use a specific user while running testcases on web

Tags: c#, selenium, azure-pipelines, web-testing

I have set up an Azure pipeline to run my web-testing application. The pipeline uses 6 agents running in parallelism. I faced the problem that some testcases are failed while running parallel although they passed when I ran them in my PC.

I'd like to ask if there is a way to configure the pipeline so that each agent use a specific user for testing.

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let us know if you would like further assistance.

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to ask if there is a way to configure the pipeline so that each agent use a specific user for testing.

I am afraid this could not be achieved for now.

Check this article: [Test agent, Test Controller and MSTEST FAQ](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vstsqualitytools/2010/10/24/test-agent-test-controller-and-mstest-faq/) (Qustion 21), it should be also applied to VS test:

> **Will Test Agents allow you to impersonate another user? Or does the
>   Test Agent always kick of tests as the user its configured start up
>   as**?
>
> There is no built in support for impersonation, so by default tests
>   run under the identity of the test agent. If this is something you
>   really need, you could write a unit test extension that does the
>   impersonation for you.

So, We could not specify the user in the Azure pipeline test step, the test will running with the agent.

As a workaround, you can try to change the agent service account to the specific account of the user. Or just deploy a new agent to run with the specific account, a sample for your reference : [Running Unit Tests on different machine during TFS 2015 build](http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2016/06/04/running-unit-tests-on-different-machine-during-tfs-2015-build/).

Hope this helps.